# identify which sidekiq process belongs to which application

Tags: ruby, background-process, sidekiq

I have 5+ Applications running on my system which are using `Sidekiq` for background process. How to identify which `sidekiq process` belongs to which application.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a "call this Sidekiq method" sort of answer, but I can give you an approach.  Using the Sidekiq server middleware, you can create a Redis key (e.g. "Process_") and assign it the name of the app, then it's just a simple matter of looking up the value of the key to determine which app created it.  If you want to go the opposite direction, create a key based on the app name (e.g. "application_") as a set and add the process id as a member.  There are examples of server middleware use in the Sidekiq Wiki, and you can dig through the Sidekiq code and refer to the Redis documentation to determine how to set keys in Redis.

Hope this helps.